# Argument of type is not assignable to parameter of type 'CreateAxiosDefaults

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, types, axios

I'm creating a lib using Node and Typescript. I have this code in my `api.ts` file

```
import axios, { AxiosInstance } from 'axios'
import {
  IAxiosStruct,
  BaseError,
  BASE_URL,
  excludeFields,
  handleAxiosError,
} from './utils'

export class TermiiCore {
  public request: AxiosInstance

  constructor(public apiKey: string) {
    this.apiKey = apiKey
    this.request = axios.create({
      baseURL: BASE_URL,
      headers: {
        Accept: 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
    })
  }

  public async useRequest(req: IAxiosStruct) {
    try {
      const customHeaders = excludeFields(
        ['common', 'delete', 'get', 'head', 'put', 'patch', 'post'],
        this.request.defaults.headers
      )

      const getUrl = this.request.defaults.baseURL
      const requestInstance = await axios.request({
        url: `${getUrl}${req.url}`,
        method: req.method,
        headers: customHeaders,
        data: req.data,
      })
      return requestInstance
    } catch (error) {
      throw new BaseError({ message: handleAxiosError(error) })
    }
  }
}
```

and using it in `message.ts`

```
import { TermiiCore } from '../../api'
import { BaseError, handleAxiosError } from '../../utils'
import { SendMessageDto } from './message.dto'

export class Message extends TermiiCore {
  constructor(apiKey: string) {
    super(apiKey)
  }
  public async sendSMS(data: SendMessageDto) {
    try {
      const requestObj = {
        method: 'POST',
        url: `/sms/send`,
        data,
      }

      const response = await this.useRequest(requestObj)
      return response
    } catch (error) {
      throw new BaseError({ message: handleAxiosError(error) })
    }
  }
}
```

However, when I run `pnpm run build`, I get

```
Argument of type '{ baseURL: string; headers: { Accept: string; 'Content-Type': string; }; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'CreateAxiosDefaults<any>'.
  Property 'string' is missing in type '{ baseURL: string; headers: { Accept: string; 'Content-Type': string; }; }' but required in type 'CreateAxiosDefaults<any>'.
```

I'm not sure what the issue is, I have tried different approaches but nothing works so far.

Here is the [code](https://github.com/peoray/termii-node-sdk/tree/switch-messaging)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the minor version 4 for axios (from `1.3.x` to `1.4.x`) this issue seems to be happening. I've tried to figure it out myself and saw the [changelog](https://github.com/axios/axios/blob/v1.x/CHANGELOG.md) for axios, but the only difference between the versions is that the latter one has exported a type.

Changing to version `1.3.x` should make your library compile successfully.